# AutoMapper - Custom type convert using property attributes

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to work out if it is possible to use a custom type convert for a mapping using the available attributes (e.g. ValueConverterAttribute).  For example ...

```
public class Source 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}

[AutoMap(typeof(Source), Reverse = true)]
public class Destination
{
    [?? ValueCoverter ??]
    public CustomType Value1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomType
{
    private string _someValue { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public CustomType(string someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }
    
    // Do some stuff with _someValue ...
}
```

... then in my Mapper configuration ...

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddMaps(typeof(Destination));
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

Source source = new Source()
{
   Value1 = "Some value"
};

Destination destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
```

My question is, can I use the `[ValueConverter]` attribute to apply a custom type converter on the *Destination.Value1* property?  I can't seem to find any examples where the ValueConverter attribute is used.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?q=ValueConverter

Comment: Thanks for the link @LucianBargaoanu ... I found an example in the Unit Test (for some reaosn I couldn't see it before when I looked).  However, my code is very similar to the Unit test, but I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` error in my Mapper Configuration code.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Start from that working code. And, step by step, add stuff to make it more like your failing case. That will give you a repro. Hopefully then you'll be able to see whether you did smth wrong or it's an AM bug.